# Execute next command if previous command exited with 0 **OR** 1

Tags: bash, shell

Culprit: `diff`. `diff` doesn't play well with `&&` - it exits with code 1 if there are differences, and doesn't care that all you want is the content of the diff, regardless of whether it contains any differences or not - **but but but** you still want to terminate on true error conditions like ENOENT.

This is a bit of a code golf question. What is the tightest bash syntax that implements the intention "run next command if previous command exited with **either** 0 **or** 1 but **not** >1"?

Alternatively, is there a standard utility that can be used to execute a command and "remap" its exit code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
diff file1 file2; (( $? < 2 )) && echo "Eureka"
```

or you COULD define a `diff` function like:

```
 diff() { command diff "$@"; rc="$?"; (( rc == 1 )) && rc=0; return "$rc"; }
```

and then `diff file1 file2` would exit with status `0` instead of `1` if the `diff` command would exit `1`.

I'd recommend if you're going to do that you use a different name for the function though, and just remember to call THAT when you need it, e.g.:

```
 my_diff() { diff "$@"; rc="$?"; (( rc == 1 )) && rc=0; return "$rc"; }
```

Comment: I must redirect diff's output to a file, will that combine with the above?

Comment: Sure, nothing in the above has anything to do with output redirection - just do `diff file1 file2 > out` like always.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `&&`, just check `$?` explicitly.

```
diff file1 file2
if [ $? -gt 1 ]
then exit 1
fi
```

Comment: There is a very good reason why I don't want a many-lines solution.

Comment: it's probably not as good a reason as you think. But you should update the question if there are more details.

Comment: Reason: simultaneous requirement of readability, simplicity, brevity and inline-ness in the context of an already complex build spec. The complexity of the build spec file is juuuuust such that I would have to split it into several files if any single build command were to blow up from a one-liner to a script - and I want to avoid splitting the build spec. But that's IRRELEVANT. This is just one of a billion possible scenarios in which someone might want a one-liner. "I want to make it shorter" intention should enjoy immunity from XY problem investigation.